# ReactJs : Unable to remove script when navigating to different pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, zendesk

I have a react app. In one of the page I am loading zendesk widget using a script. But once the script is loaded, when I open any other pages, widget is still visible.

I load script by invoking the below custom hook created

```
useScript('https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=xxxx');
```

Below is the snipped of the custom hook. This works fine and the script is loaded when the invoking component loads. But when I navigate to different pages, the script is not removed. I can see the widget loaded by script from previous page is visible in all the pages.

```
const useScript = url => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');

        script.src = url;
        script.async = true;
        script.id = 'ze-snippet';

        document.body.appendChild(script);
        
        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, []);
};

export default useScript;
```

Comment: Why do you want the script to be removed? What benefits do you get from that behaviour? You don’t want to remove the script, you want to close the widget

Comment: The ultimate goal is that I dont want the widget to be visible on other pages.

Comment: You need to call `hide` when you navigate away from the page: https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/widget-messaging/web/core/#hide. But then you'll need to call `show` when you come back to that page.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was able to fix it by building on top of your suggestion. Can you mark this as answer and close this one.